# Matrix multiplication using Threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, matrix

I've got a problem in my program that creates 2 matrices A and B (initialize each cell with 1), and it calculates the matrix C=A*B using threads(each thread calculate one row).
The problem is that it works sometimes, and sometimes it doesn't.

```
package multiplier;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Multiplier extends Threads{

    static int[][] A,B,C;
    static int x;
    int row;

    public Multiplier(int row){
        this.row=row;
    }


    @Override
    public void run(){
        for(int a=0;a<x;a++){
            C[row][a]=0;
            for(int b=0;b<x;b++){
                C[row][a]+=A[row][b]*B[b][a];
            }
        }
    }

    //main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        x= new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        A= new int[x][x];
        B= new int[x][x];
        C= new int[x][x];
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<x;j++){
                A[i][j]=1;
                B[i][j]=1;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
            new Multiplier(i).start();

        }

        for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<x;j++){
                System.out.print(C[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what is class `Threads`? maybe you meant `Thread`?

Comment: Thread synchronization is probably why this is only working sometimes

Comment: I've used "synchronized" to synchronize the threads but it doesn't work